# Why does the simple present tense change to the past progressive (rather than the simple past) in some cases?

Tags: tenses

Consider:

> "What are you up to right now?"
> "I **hope** to secure an appointment with her."

As opposed to:

> "What were you up to just then?"
> "I **was hoping** to secure an appointment with her."

Yes, I know it sounds "more natural." But: why does it?

Comment: These sentences do not correspond to a real context in my opinion: "to be up to sth" means "to be doing sth" (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-up-to), which is an action verb, whereas "to hope" is a stative verb. The answerer does not answer the question asked but rather another one, such  as for instance, "What about this prospect of a job you had in mind?".

Answer (score 1):

The following are just as acceptable, in my opinion.

> "What are you up to right now?"
> "I'm hoping to secure an appointment with her."

> "What were you up to just then?"
> "I hoped to secure an appointment with her."

I don't think there's a very significant difference in meaning, it's mainly a matter of individual style.